# Exit status of remote shell command with backticks

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Why does the following command returns 0 ? Given the `$` is escaped, should it not use the remote variable ? It seems to be using the local variable.

```
echo `ssh <user>@<hostname> "dat; echo \$?"`
bash: dat: command not found
0
```

whereas it works perfectly in single quotes

```
echo `ssh <user>@<hostname> 'dat; echo $?'`
bash: dat: command not found
127
```

I understand that the cleanest way of doing this would be to get the exit status of SSH itself as it exits with the exit status of the last remote command.

Comment: You have to escape it again for the backticks. This is why you should never use backticks and use `$()` instead.

Comment: You would have the same problem with `$(...)`. The problem is that the command that is sent to the remote host is *again* subject to shell expansion.

Comment: Also, `echo $(...)` is pointless; just run the command. All you are doing is capturing the standard output of the command, then writing it back out to standard output immediately.

Comment: @chepner, it actually works with `$(...)`

Comment: So does `ssh ...` with an appropriate (simpler) argument. Using `echo` only adds complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With double quotes in backquotes, the string is quoted twice, so you need to double escape it:

```
echo `ssh <user>@<hostname> "dat; echo \\$?"`
```

Comment: Thank You @choroba

Comment: As mentioned by @chepner, `echo` is pointless in this case - you can invoke ssh directly: `ssh <user>@<hostname> "dat; echo \\$?"`

Comment: Maybe `echo` was used as a placeholder for something else?

Comment: Yes, echo is pointless, i initially wanted to save the value in a variable and check the value of the variable.  So `echo`ed it.